# pip --version zsh: no such file or directory: usr/local/bin/pip3

Tags: python, macos, pip

I am new to coding, and I think I messed up with pip... Can someone help me with this?
I am using Macbook, version 10.15.2.
I think I tried alias? I can't remember... 
But I don't have trouble with pip with bash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `python3 -m pip`

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem I spent weeks trying to solve it and refused to reinstall macOS.

**1) The cause of the problem**

- You have installed different distribution of python

**2) Solution**

- Open Terminal
- Write `cd ~`
- Then write 'vim .zshrc'
- Press `i` set the pip and python alias and remove any-other alias (in my case I set it to be conda)

***NOTE I HAVE REMOVED EVERY PYTHON DISTRIBUTION EXCEPT FOR PYTHON 2.7 AND ANACONDA ***